Rust moving values from nested option
Is there an easy/readable way to move multiple values from nested option without cloning (because copying vectors is costly)?
Consider code like this
struct A {
    pub b: Option<B>
}

struct B {
    pub c: Option<C>,
    pub d: Option<C>,
    pub e: Option<C>,
}

struct C {
    pub v1: Option<Vec<i64>>,
    pub v2: Option<Vec<i64>>,
}

struct Result {
    pub v11: Option<Vec<i64>>,
    pub v22: Option<Vec<i64>>,
}

fn main() {
    let a= Some(A {
        b: Some(B {
            c: Some(C {
                v1: Some(vec![1, 2, 3]),
                v2: Some(vec![4, 5, 6]),
            }),
            d: Some(C {
                v1: Some(vec![7, 8, 9]),
                v2: Some(vec![10, 11, 12]),
            }),
            e: Some(C {
                v1: Some(vec![13, 14, 15]),
                v2: Some(vec![16, 17, 18]),
            }),
        }),
    });

    // Construct Result such that v11 = v1 from c and v22 = v2 from d if all fields are Some
    let result = Result {
        v11: a.and_then(|a| a.b).and_then(|b| b.c).and_then(|c| c.v1),
        v22: a.and_then(|a| a.b).and_then(|b| b.d).and_then(|d| d.v2),
    };
    
}

This obviously fails on
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `a`
    --> src/main.rs:42:14
     |
22   |     let a= Some(A {
     |         - move occurs because `a` has type `Option<A>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
41   |         v11: a.and_then(|a| a.b).and_then(|b| b.c).and_then(|c| c.v1),
     |              - ----------------- `a` moved due to this method call
     |              |
     |              help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
42   |         v22: a.and_then(|a| a.b).and_then(|b| b.d).and_then(|d| d.v2),
     |              ^ value used here after move
     |


I could simultaneously move (c,d) from a.b separately and then move from those into the Result, but for even larger (deeper, more branched) nested structures this gets absolutely unreadable.
Reason why I need this: I would like to "flatten" a protobuf message (giant structure of Options), filter out some fields and transform some values without copying everything.

I propose a two-step approach:
let (c, d) = a
    .and_then(|a| a.b)
    .map(|b| (b.c, b.d))
    .unwrap_or((None, None));

let result = Result {
    v11: c.and_then(|c| c.v1),
    v22: d.and_then(|d| d.v2),
};

It pulls the c and d values from the a.b chain at the same time (with None if they don't exist) so it can then use them separately for filling in the Result.
Or a different formulation that does the last and_thens inside the map:
let (v11, v22) = a
    .and_then(|a| a.b)
    .map(|b| (
        b.c.and_then(|c| c.v1),
        b.d.and_then(|d| d.v2),
    ))
    .unwrap_or((None, None));

let result = Result { v11, v22 };


This is 2step approach is what I wished to avoid (since it gets pretty hard to read when you are actually moving 7 values and not 2 or 3), but it seems to be the only one reasonably working.

Option helper methods won't work here, since they move the entire thing.
This can be done with match, but much nicer is to use immediately invoked closures (or try blocks):

let result: Result = (|| {
    let a = a?;
    let b = a.b?;
    let v11 = (|| {
        let c = b.c?;
        c.v1
    })();
    let v22 = (|| {
        let c = b.d?;
        c.v2
    })();
    Some(Result { v11, v22 })
})()
.unwrap_or(Result {
    v11: None,
    v22: None,
});


You can use a bunch of Option::as_mut and then Option::take at the end.
let mut a = a;
let result = Result {
    v11: a
        .as_mut()
        .and_then(|a| a.b.as_mut())
        .and_then(|b| b.c.as_mut())
        .and_then(|c| c.v1.take()),
    v22: a
        .as_mut()
        .and_then(|a| a.b.as_mut())
        .and_then(|b| b.d.as_mut())
        .and_then(|d| d.v2.take()),
};

You could also consider a pattern match, although it's not very readable in this case.
let result = Result {
    v11: if let Some(A {
        b: Some(B {
            c: Some(C { v1, .. }),
            ..
        }),
        ..
    }) = &mut a
    {
        v1.take()
    } else {
        None
    },
    v22: if let Some(A {
        b: Some(B {
            d: Some(C { v2, .. }),
            ..
        }),
        ..
    }) = &mut a
    {
        v2.take()
    } else {
        None
    },
};

